# Changing selected="selected" to first value in a option list

Tags: html, html-select

i use a plugin, that allow users to book rooms in a hotel. I want to change the pre-selected option to the first value, with PHP or Javascript.

```
<select id="room">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
</select>
```

What i want to realize:

```
<select id="room">
   <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only have to use the *selected* HTML attribute, like this:

```
<option value="1" selected>1</option>
```

As altering an HTML element after creation is something that should be done on the client side, I think that you should use JavaScript to change the selected element, like this:

```
document.getElementById("room").selectedIndex = "0"
```